# Is it necessary to use a WordPress nonce when allowing users to download public data?

Tags: jquery, security, nonce

I am using jQuery `.load()` to load the next page of WordPress posts after a button is clicked. The next page of posts is public data (no access restrictions on it whatsoever). Should I use a [WordPress nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) check in this situation? If so, then please explain why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nonces are used to verify that a request is allowed from the sender. For public data, all GET requests are allowed, if they match existing public content.

So no, do not use a nonce for that. You have nothing to do if the nonce validation fails. That’s always a good indicator for unnecessary information.